# Power view layout issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, powerpivot, powerview

Anyone developing on power view?
I have a slicer on the year but I would like to display it in X columns instead of X rows. Its kind aeasy to do it on power pivot but I cant figure it out how to do it on power view.

Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently cannot change the layout for slicers in Power View.  It's a great feature request that I'm almost certain is already logged on Connect.  Feel free to vote for it or add it as a new one if it is not there, but we definitely do hear you :)

-Sean